# UIActivityViewController image share not working with Facebook

Tags: objective-c, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using a UIActivityViewController with

```
SPMessageProvider *messageProvider = [[SPMessageProvider alloc] initWithSubject:@"Try it out!" message:shareText];
SPImageProvider *imageProvider = [[SPImageProvider alloc] initWithImage:shareImage];
SPURLProvider *urlProvider = [SPURLProvider new];

NSArray *activityItems = @[ messageProvider, imageProvider, urlProvider ];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
```

The SPImageProvider is as follows:

```
@implementation SPImageProvider

- (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage*)image {
  self = [super initWithPlaceholderItem:@"Placeholder image item"];

  if (!self) {
    return nil;
  }

  _image = image;

  return self;
}


- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController {
  return @"";
}

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
  return _image;
}

- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
  return (__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeImage;
}

@end
```

When tapping the Facebook share option, the dialog opens but the image never appears (nor does the text, but I believe that's no longer allowed). The image shows for the Twitter option. Any idea why it doesn't work for Facebook?

Comment: Can you provide a small xcode project that showcases this behaviour? You can upload it somewhere public where we download it. Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?